# Downsampling Geotiff using summation - Gdal/Numpy

Tags: gdal, resolution, numpy

I am trying to downsample a 1 square km raster dataset to a much larger (.5 degree x .66 degree) dataset by summing all of the pixel values within this large grid cell.

gdal_warp does not contain a summation resampling method so I'm wondering if anyone has figured this out before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the version of GDAL, there are a few different resample options available; see [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-r).

### GDAL 1.10 or later using `-r average`

> average resampling, computes the weighted average of all non-NODATA contributing pixels

This isn't tested, but should look something like:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -tr 0.5 0.66 -r average fine_one_sq_km.tif coarse_average.tif
```

Then to get the *sum*, multiply the average by the number of pixels of the fine resolution raster in one pixel of the coarse resolution raster, which hopefully is constant (you could assume it is).

### GDAL 3.1 or later using `-r sum`

> compute the weighted sum of all non-NODATA contributing pixels

This should look like this:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -tr 0.5 0.66 -r sum fine_one_sq_km.tif coarse_sum.tif
```

---

Otherwise, [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.sum_labels`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.sum_labels.html) (or [`sum` for older versions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.sum.html)) can be used to aggregate multidimensional sums. But this may rely on perfect matchings between grids.

Comment: That would work but I would have to create a labeling matrix the same size as my larger resolution grid. I can do that but I was hoping there was something in numpy/scipy/gdal that looked like: gdalwarp ... -r sum ...

Comment: Multiplying the average by the number of 1 square kilometers cells could work for this (accuracy isn't my top priority).  Thanks!

Comment: Yes: avg = sum / count, so sum = avg * count.

Comment: ...I guess I over thought the problem...

Comment: Note: careful with rasters with null values. The average is calculated without considering nulls, so then to multiply that value by the number of input pixels contributing to a larger output pixel would give you an incorrect sum of the input. Setting regions of no data to 0 in the source dataset is probably a sensible idea in most cases where summation is meaningful, so that it influences the average value appropriately.

Having a `sum` resampling method would actually be an excellent contribution to gdalwarp, since it would consider no data appropriately and automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `gdalwarp` got a new `sum` method in GDAL release 3.1.0, see [release notes](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/2b949f190c7669d6c831fe0c945611712ebed6a0/gdal/NEWS#L66). Adapting from the above solution:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -tr 0.5 0.66 -r sum fine_one_sq_km.tif coarse_sum.tif
```